# Como leer archivo CSV con LinqtoExcel C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, excel

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual me permita leer un `excel` que se guarda automáticamente en mi escritorio por medio de otro programa y se reescribe automáticamente cada cierto tiempo.  Consigo leer el archivo pero cuando el programa que lo guarda esta parado o cuando el excel no esta abierto, si es uno de estos casos me da el siguiente error: "

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'El motor de base de datos Microsoft
>   Jet no pudo encontrar el objeto 'prueba.csv$'. Asegúrese de que el
>   objeto existe, y que ha escrito el nombre y la ruta de acceso al
>   objeto correctamente.'"

Mi pregunta es, ¿como puedo leer los datos de Excel mientras esta abierto?¿ Como podría leer ademas las últimas filas que se van guardando automáticamente cada cierto tiempo? Realmente lo único que me interersa mostrar en mi programa es la última fila que se guarda. Adjunto mi código. Gracias.

```
using LinqToExcel;
namespace opacimetro
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonDatos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string rutaExcel = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) +"\\prueba.csv";
        //Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) +
        //"C:\\Users\\alvar\\Desktop\\prueba.csv";
        var book = new ExcelQueryFactory(rutaExcel);

       //(from row in book.Worksheet("prueba")
        var resul = (from row in book.Worksheet("prueba")
                    let item = new Datos
                    {
                        A = row[27].Cast<string>(),
                        B = row[28].Cast<string>(),
                        C = row[29].Cast<string>()

                    }
                    select item).ToList();

        book.Dispose();


        foreach ( var item in resul)
        {
            textBox1.Text += item.A ;
            textBox2.Text += item.B ;
            textBox3.Text += item.C ; 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasta donde yo conozco, si ya tienes un excel abierto en el mismo equipo donde quieres volverlo a abrir, debes cerrar primero la instancia ya abierta o tendrás un error.

Prueba a abrir 2 veces el mismo excel (haciendo doble click 2 veces sobre el archivo) y observa el resultado.

Un saludo